# VBA Macro that scrapes HTML pulls some wrong elements

Tags: html, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am having problem scraping some `HTML`.

Here is the [URL](http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=icld&type=10-Q%20&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=20) where my `macro` is scrapping and below is the excerpt of the code:

```
Set els = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    For Each el In els
        If Trim(el.innertext) = "Documents" Then
            colDocLinks.Add el.href
        End If
    Next el
```

As you can see if you open the `URL` we run into search results; then the macro finds all `links` in the search table and puts them in a `Collection` named `colDocLinks`

However the search results have on their table `10-Q` documents which i want to include but they also have different kind of animals which i do **not** want to include like `10-Q/A` documents...

---

How can i modify the loop so that it **explicitly** adds **only** 10-Q's with nothing attached to them in the collection and **not** others like 10-Q/A's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public WithEvents objIE As InternetExplorer


Sub LaunchIE()
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate "http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=icld&type=10-Q%20&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=20"

End Sub

Private Sub objIE_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)

Dim localIE As InternetExplorer
Set localIE = pDisp

Dim doc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument3
Set doc = localIE.Document

Dim tdElements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim td As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Set tdElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each td In tdElements

    If td.innerText = "10-Q" Then

        Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Set tr = td.parentElement

        Dim childrenElements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim child As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Set childrenElements = tr.Children
        For Each child In childrenElements
            If child.innerText = " Documents" Then
                'Handle found element
            End If
        Next

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for your courtesy at the moment work is hammering me but the second i have free time i will test this and notify you ASAP.

Comment: The above code skips 7 of the 12 desired anchor elements. If you make the following changes, all of the desired anchor elements are found. The line `Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElement` should change to `Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElement2` and the line `Set childrenElements = tr.Children` should change to `Set childrenElements = tr.getElementsByTagName("a")`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to find and extract the exact links I was looking for.  Something like this:

```
Dim RegEx As RegExp
Set RegEx = New RegExp
Dim match As match

With RegEx
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
End With

RegEx.Pattern = "<td nowrap="nowrap">10-Q</td>.+?<a href=""(.+?)\.htm"">"

For Each match In RegEx.Execute(Selection)
    colDocLinks.Add match
Next
```

I didn't test the regular expression above, so it may need some adjustment.  You would need to include a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 for this to work.